# Changing code from MS SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How can I convert this from MS SQL SERVER to MySQL?

```
/****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[geolocation_refresh_geography] Script Date: 05/08/2012 22:02:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create procedure [dbo].[geolocation_refresh_geography]
as
update locations
SET geolocation = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
where geolocation is null
GO
```

My code is causing errors on line 4, not sure why?

```
create procedure geolocation_refresh_geography()
BEGIN
update locations
SET geolocation = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(Longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
where geolocation is null
END
```

Comment: I'm assuming that block two is your MySQL code, if so, the reason it is failing is because mysql doesn't have the geography bit. The STPointFromText is something that you are going to have to do manually. Most likely, this is going to have to be coded externally.

Comment: Why on earth does it have to be done manually or externally? MySQL supports almost exactly the same OGC standards as SQL Server - it's just the syntax is slightly different. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the MySQL Migration Toolkit?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/mysql-migration-toolkit-indepth-sourcedb-mssql.html

It is a bit tough to find these days but I believe you can also you MySQL Workbench to accomplish this.
http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

I would recommend just migrating your entire schema which should port the procedure for you.

Comment: I'm borrowing code from a coworker so I don't have access to the physical DB in order to covert it from the MySQL Workbench.

Comment: disregard this but who are the jerks downing my questions when I performed background research before turning to StackOverflow?

Comment: No promises for this being a solution, but if you have a copy of SQL server on hand, you can always create a really simple schema with this procedure and attempt to migrate that. I'm really afraid that the geography stuff is going to be your brick wall though.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, MySQL supports spatial data only if configured with Spatial Extensions enabled (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html). Assuming you've got that setup, you just need to adapt the SQL Server syntax to the appropriate MySQL method.

MySQL has a PointFromText() method (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-values.html#function_pointfromtext) that mirrors the behaviour of SQL Server's STPointFromText() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933979.aspx), so you could simply replace the reference to *geography::STPointFromText* with *PointFromText*

However, for inserting points from a single latitude/longitude coordinate pair as you are doing, the easiest method to use is Point() (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-values.html#function_point), in which case your code simply becomes:

```
create procedure geolocation_refresh_geography()
BEGIN
update locations
SET geolocation = Point(Longitude, Latitude)
where geolocation is null
END
```